Basic SwiftUI code not working in landscape
I am integrating a SwiftUI view in a UIKit application, my SwiftUI view is cut off when switching from portrait mode to landscape mode. I have followed tutorial online and my ViewController looks like:
@IBSegueAction func embedSwiftUIView(_ coder: NSCoder) -> UIViewController? {
    return UIHostingController(coder: coder, rootView: MySwiftUIView())
}

My SwiftUI view just renders some placeholder text:
var body: some View {
    Text("Placeholder")
}

Everything works ok in the preview in both landscape and portrait but when use the simulator (run the app). I get a blank screen on landscape mode (as if the text was cut off)
Preview:


Simulator:


What could I be doing wrong? I have tried so many things, geometryreaders etc nothing works. I want the simulator to behave like the preview and have the text in the center
